# How to get first index in map array? Js

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to get first index in array and map loop.

```
selectedValue: number;

   let test =  this.indexOfSelectedExercise.sets.map((set, index) => {
      if(!set.completed) {  
        this.selectedValue = set.values; 
      }
    })

    console.log('in' , test)
  }
```

I need to get this.selectedValue = set.values.
Right now i get last index because loop thourght all array and get last item.

set.values is example 4,5,6,7,8 and my selectedValue is 8 but i need to be 4

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using map incorrectly. Perhaps .forEach() or simply accessing the first index would be easier? Or perhaps I don't understand the question.

Anyway, a simple way to make `this.selectedValue` to be the first value, rather than the last would be:

```js
this.selectedValue = null;
let test =  this.indexOfSelectedExercise.sets.map((set, index) => {
      if(!set.completed && !this.selectedValue) {  
        this.selectedValue = set.values; 
      }
    })

console.log(this.selectedValue) // Should be the first value set
```

But if you explain more clearly exactly what you want done, I could probably help more. I really think that `.map` is the wrong tool for the job here.